# What kind of black and yellow insect has a zebra like pattern?

Tags: insects, identification

Can anyone help me identify a insect with the following features:

- black and yellow
- long feelers
- body is tapered toward the back
- zebra like pattern on the shell
- about 1.5 inches long
- found in central Texas

Here's what it looks like:

[image: Black and yellow insect]

Comment: perhaps indicate what plant it was in, whether he had any friends, and why it's a gardening issue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like a [Cottonwood Borer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cottonwood_borer).  I am from Ontario, Canada and here Asian Long Horned Beetles are a concern. I do not know if this will help, but [here](http://www.mnr.gov.on.ca/en/Business/Forests/2ColumnSubPage/STEL02_166979.html) is more information on the Ontario situation.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Cottonwood Borer. I grew up in Bellaie, Houston Texas and we had 2 cottonwood trees in our from yard, we had tons of these terrifying things in yard. They'd crunch loudly on a branch all way thru intil branch fell of. They also fly...ick! If big black flying cockroaches weren't scary enough, Texas has these monster bugs too. I've heard they have a wicked bite but I never got close enough to find out. Since I'm absolutely terrified of these beetles and roaches, I moved to Colorado and haven't seen one here... I only go home to visit family and friends in Fall and Winter when these disgusting, vile critters usually hibernate.